# How to add two numpy arrays into one?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have an array `preds` which has values `0,1 or 2` .

The shape and value of `preds` looks something like this:

```
torch.Size([1, 256, 256])
tensor([[[1, 1, 0,  ..., 1, 1, 2],
         [1, 0, 1,  ..., 1, 1, 1],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 1, 1, 1],
         ...,
         [0, 1, 1,  ..., 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1,  ..., 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1,  ..., 1, 1, 1]]])
```

I am only concerned with 2nd and 3rd dimentions (`256 x 256`). I want to create a mask using `matplotlib` which plots (separately) `0` , `1`, and `2`. Basically I want to visualize all places in an image we have `0`, where do we have `1` and where do we have `2`. I want separtae plots for it.

I am thinking something like. For example for class `1` :

1. Get idices of places where we have 1 and assign them value
   1 and assign other indices a value 0.
2. Plot it using `plt.show`

Example:

```
zero = (preds==0).nonzero() #index of all values which have 0 
nonzero = (preds!=0).nonzero()    # index of all value which are not 0
# assign 1 to all zero
# assign 0 to all nonzero
# join the above two array
# plot the array
```

I just don't know how to add these two array (`nonzero` and `zero`) in my pseudo code.

Is there a more Pythonic way of doing it? I don't want to loop over all index values and then assign values to them.

Comment: Look into `np.where` with three arguments, first being that mask.

Comment: @DavidBuck Actually! That's my own question. I thought my previous question didn't publish due to some error so I published it again with a different title. Funny that it turned up.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate question. I'll delete the question. My page didn't load so i thought it didn't publish

Comment: @Divakar np.where only return me the indices if I understand correctly. I already have them. I don't know how to proceed next.

Comment: Did you read the docs? @Sulphur

Comment: @Divakar Yes, it `it returns the indices of elements in an input array where the given condition is satisfied.` I dont want that! Example: I don't what the locations where something is true or false: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-where-in-python/

Comment: You need to read again then. It says : `Parameters
conditionarray_like, bool
Where True, yield x, otherwise yield y.`.

Comment: `np.where(pred[0])` returns me the locations `(array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 255, 255, 255]), array([  0,   1,   3, ..., 253, 254, 255]))` I want to make a combined array/mask eventually. I don't think `np.where` will help.

Comment: So if you have 256 different values in the array, you want 256 different arrays created first?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using `np.where` as someone suggested in the comments. It looks like this:

```
#preds in the matrix where I want the 0 and 1s
preds_clear = np.where(preds==0, 1, 0)
plt.imshow(preds_clear[0,:,:])
```